# How can I make the following Flask application work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, python-requests

I am trying to make a contact us form for my Flask web application and I am stuck, I think url_for is not working properly.

I have the following Flask application: https://github.com/spectra93/dkodder

I am doing an action = "{{url_for('contact')}}" in the form tag to render the contact template using the code in the application.py file def contact():

I am killing myself with the fact that is not producing any error but for some reason, it does not process the code.

Please help me on this and feel free to access the dkodder repo posted in the link above.

Comment: Please include the python file and the template from where you are calling the route to the question. It is not convenient to search it in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

The same code is working for me, I get response "Thanks! Message has been sent successfully." after submitting form. I guess you didn't notice the message or can you like point out what exactly you are expecting from the form.

I also see it makes POST request on method contact() on clicking send message button which has `url_for('contact')`.

Apart from that I see small issue with below code which is unrelated to the question.

```
@app.route("/email")
    def email():
        return render_template("email.html") # it was contact.html and there is no such template
```

Comment: I noticed that mistake but still not working my aim is to do a contact form for this website. I have modified the code and make some progress but still, I don't get the email. Please check updated version of the code.

Comment: Sorry I missed to check your comment, I am wondering if you have fixed that by now. you need some SMTP configurations to do that.